# Move events between calendars

Tags: fullcalendar

How do I enable dragging of events between different fullcalendars on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the editable property to 'true' it will allow you to drag events.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/

Comment: I'm afraid that only makes it possible to drag event within the same calendar, not between separate calendars.

Comment: Check this link. 
http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2010/05/drag-external-events-into-fullcalendar.html

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the external-dragging demo and posted the code to the comments on http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=550.

You will have to remember which calendar you are dragging from (on dragStart) so that you can move the event from on calendar to the other.

Hope this helps.